# Call virtual functions within the class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++ we should not call in constructors/destructor virtual functions.

What if I explicitly call these functions with the class scope?

Essentially we are saying that we don't want to profit from virtuality.

Is the pseudo-code below correct?

```
 struct CA{ 
    CA(){ CA::foo();} // calling foo() without CA is wrong
    virtual int foo(){} 
 };

 struct CB{ 
    CB(){ CB::foo();} // calling foo() without CB is wrong
    virtual int foo(); 
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this or are you just curious?

Comment: With some compilers it is not wrong but it only calls it's own foo, ie not behaving like a virtual fn in the constructor.

Comment: You do not need the explicit scope resolution operator: the compiler does it for you. In fact, the compiler doing that is the reason why calling virtuals from constructors in C++ is not in itself a bad thing (unlike other languages, where this practice is a lot less safe).

Comment: @QuentinUK - with **all** compilers that's the correct behavior. A virtual call goes to the class that's currently being constructed, which often isn't the (unconstructed) most derived type.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's what I thought but there are so many changes all the time I wasn't certain. I assumed that when abruzzo-forte-e-gentile said it was wrong that he had tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: The **code** is correct, the **comments** are not.

Comment: @David whether the comments are "wrong" or not ventures into the realm of opinion.  Calling a virtual function in a constructor is dangerous.  Regardless of whether the compiler thinks the unqualified version is equivalent to the qualified version, you want to underline in BIG RED LETTERS that the qualified version is what you really want, and comments are often TL;DR.   Adding the class name takes little effort and makes things clearer.

Comment: @Spencer: Calling a virtual function in a constructor is dubious, but perfectly defined in the language. According to the language definition, it is **correct**, whether any sensible guidelines should allow or forbid this particular case is a different question.  The comments claim that it is **wrong** to call `foo()` directly, it is **not**, thus the comment is wrong. Bad style? Code smell? that's a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `CB::foo()` is not dynamically dispatched, so there are no unfortunate surprises awaiting you or anyone reading this code. It's perfectly fine. In fact, it would also be fine to simply call `foo()`, as that is by Standard identical in this scenario, although you might want to leave a comment for your coworkers.

Comment: +1 Why would you leave a comment for your coworkers? *Not* leaving that comment would be a good way to teach them something new ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: If you want to teach your coworkers, talk to them. Source is the wrong place for teaching, clarity is paramount here.

Comment: @DevSolar Well, this was a tongue-in-cheek comment, aimed at highlighting the difference between "teaching them" and "teaching them a lesson" :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight,@devsolar.  You would indeed expect basic knowledge from co-workers, but if there is the slighest risk of confusion, I would also suggest to add it in comment.  Reminds me of a colleague that wrote lengthy combinations of &&, || and other operators without parenthesis, assuming that everybody knows what it does.  Well, sometimes it doesn't and it's easy to make a mistake.  Code must be readable, and if it's confusing, you are just introducing new delays.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct CA{ 
   CA(){ CA::foo(); } // calling foo() without CA is wrong
   virtual int foo(){}
};

struct CB { 
   CB(){ CB::foo(); } // calling foo() without CB is wrong
   virtual int foo(); 
};
```

I don't see any noticeable difference between the two classes, considering that a non-pure virtual function must be defined within the program, there must be a definition of `CB::foo` somewhere and it does not really matter if it is defined inside the class definition or somewhere else.

In neither case the call to `foo()` (without explicit qualification) is *wrong*. The difference between using `foo()` and `Type::foo()` is that in the first case you are using dynamic dispatch that will eventually call the *final overrider* of the function *at this time*, while in the qualified case (`Type::foo`) the extra qualification inhibits dynamic dispatch.

It is important to note the *at this time*. The dynamic type of the *object* changes during construction in a type hierarchy. While evaluating the base constructor, the dynamic type is `base` and thus the *final overrider* can only be picked up from that class. After the base constructor completes, the dynamic type changes to the next type in the hierarchy, and the final overrider can be picked from those two types and so on.

```
struct base {
   base() { foo() };
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};
struct d1 : base {
   d1() : base() { foo() };
};
struct d2 : d1 {
   d2() : d1() { foo() };
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "d2\n"; }
};
```

Construction of an object of type `d2` will start by constructing the `base` subobject, the `foo()` call there will be dispatched to the final overrider which at this time only considers the `base` type and it prints `"base"`. The `d1` constructor is then executed, which calls `foo()` picking the final overrider at this level, which is still `base::foo()`. After that completes the `d2` constructor is evaluated. At this point the final overrider is `d2::foo()` and `"d2"` is printed yielding:

```
base
base
d2
```

Note that even thought he only complete object that we are creating is of type `d2`, it behaved temporarily as a `base` object, then as a `d1` object and only when the `d2` constructor starts executing it starts behaving as a `d2` object and calls `d2`. This is considered confusing by many.

Note that because the *dynamic* type of the object at each level is exactly the type of the constructor being evaluated, the final overrider will always be dispatched to that type. Adding the extra qualification does not make much of a difference except when dealing with...

**Pure virtual functions**

Pure virtual functions can have a definition. The pure qualifier means that derived types must provide a definition of that virtual function, and it also means that the pure virtual function (if defined) will never be called when dynamic dispatch is performed. In that particular case, the extra qualification that disables the dynamic dispatch can be used to call that particular implementation:

```
struct base {
   base() { base::foo(); }  // [*]
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};
void base::foo() { std::cout << "base\n"; }
struct derived : base {
   derived() : base() { foo(); base::foo(); }
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "derived\n"; }
};
```

This is the only case where the unqualified call to `foo` in `[*]` is illformed, as when that constructor is being evaluated `foo` is pure virtual and there is no *final overrider*. On the other hand, adding the qualification disables dynamic dispatch and the code above will compile and run. Also note that in the `derived` constructor you can use the extra qualification to select a particular definition of the function `base::foo` that might not be the final overrider at this level. The code above prints:

```
base
derived
base
```